# C++ Boost Docset

Tags: boost, documentation

Is there a docset for Boost?  I'ld like to add it to Dash for offline documentation search, and can't find one anywhere.  All attempts of my own to build it have failed, rather spectacularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed today that Dash has updated with a Boost Docset, based on Doxygen.  Not sure how they got it, but it seems to have everything in there.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I've found; they don't even offer a complete set of offline docs, let alone a Dash docset. (Alas, the PDFs that Marchall Clow mentions are only a small subset.)

I've been toying with the idea of creating one, but like you I gave up in frustration. If you want to collaborate, drop me a line!

As I understand it, you'd need to:

- Create an offline mirror of the entire set of Boost docs. This is easy enough, something like the following should work:

  ```
  wget --mirror -p --no-parent --convert-links -P ./boost_docs \ 
      http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/libraries.htm
  ```
- Index the docs. (This is the hard part.) Scrape the HTML and try and pull out interesting semantic elements: classes, functions, types and so on, and create an index.

  Many of the components of Boost seem to use a consistent documentation format, but what complicates things is that many other components have their own, idiosyncratic approach, and their HTML markup is not all semantic. (`boost::filesystem`'s docs appear to have been created using Microsoft Frontpage. I wish I was joking.)